# Serverspec で 範囲指定をしたい (Rspec でいう be_within + of や start_with..)

Tags: ruby

Serverspec で数値の範囲指定がしたいのですが、上手くいきません

- 当方環境

  - serverspec-2.31.0
  - ruby 2.2.3p173

要件としては
***config fileにある設定値に対し、あいまいな値によるテストがしたい***
です。

- 例

  1. php-fpmのpool configに以下の設定がある
     `start_servers = 10`
  2. start_serversの値が 9以上20以下だったらTestをpassにしたいなど

file resource typeにはそのような判定機能がありません

そこでcommand resource typeを使い戻り値を Rspecの be_within + of による範囲指定(あいまいな検査)でTestを行おうと考えましたが、上手くいきませんでした

`its(:stdout) { should be_within(9.0).of(20.0) }`
とか
`expect(:stdout).to be_within(9.0).of(20.0)`
とか書いても
`:stdout` に当然Symbolで返ってきていて、String型で 10\nが入っています
それをCast (明示的な型変換)をしても0になってしまいます
(inspect.to_f or {to_s,inspect}.to_f などしても 0になってしまう)

また、start_with().and end_with()で指定しても成功しませんでした

```ruby
describe command("awk '\$1~/start_servers/{ print \$3}' /etc/php-fpm.d/#{ENV['PJCODE']}.conf") do
    it "start_servers は 2から10までの値である" do
      expect(:stdout).to_s.to_i { start_with(2).and end_with(10) }
      expect(:stdout).to start_with(2).and end_with(10)
    end

    it "start_servers は 12から15までの値ではないのでerrorになる" do
      expect(:stdout).to_s.to_i { start_with(12).and end_with(15) }
      p expect(:stdout).to_s.to_i
    end
  end
```

- Result

```
.......................................................................... Failed on 10.1.1.100
F0
...

Failures:

  1) Command "awk '$1~/start_servers/{ print $3}' /etc/php-fpm.d/wp-vagrant.conf" start_servers は 2から10までの値である
     On host `wordpress'
     Failure/Error: expect(:stdout).to start_with(2).and end_with(10)
          expected :stdout to start with 2

       ...and:

          expected :stdout to end with 10

     # ./spec/php-fpm/main_spec.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 4.27 seconds (files took 0.6914 seconds to load)
78 examples, 1 failure
```

やはり型変換ができていません

- should be > の場合

```ruby
its(:stdout) { should be.inspect.to_i > 12 }
its(:stdout) { should be.inspect.to_i > 9 }
its(:stdout) { should be.to_s.to_i > 12 }
its(:stdout) { should be.to_s.to_i > 9 }
its(:stdout) { should.inspect.to_i > 12 }
its(:stdout) { should.inspect.to_i > 9 }
its(:stdout) { should.to_s.to_i > 12 }
its(:stdout) { should.to_s.to_i > 9 }
```

- これらは全てTestがスルー (無視でpassed)されてしまいます

  - この例ですと:stdoutが"10\n"なのでそれを数値に変換したとして > 12はfailed になってほしいです
- どうもbe_within(), start_with()の時と同じく型変換で Falseになり、 0:Fixnum と変換されているのかと思いましたが、以下でしたので0になる原因がよくわかっていません...

```
[61] pry(main)> 0 === false ? true : false
=> false
[28] pry(main)> Process.wait
=> 18988
[29] pry(main)> $?.exitstatus
=> 0
[30] pry(main)> $?.exitstatus === true ? true : false
=> false
[31] pry(main)> $?.exitstatus
=> 0
[32] pry(main)> $?.exitstatus === false ? true : false
=> false

[33] pry(main)> p !0
false
=> false
[34] pry(main)> p !!0
true
=> true
[35] pry(main)> p 0
0
=> 0
[36] pry(main)> p !1
false
=> false
[37] pry(main)> p !!1
true
=> true
```

なにか良い方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいますでしょうか?
新しいresource typeを用意する以外は方法がなさそうでしょうか?

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のように`its('stdout.to_i')`を検証するとよいのではないでしょうか。

```ruby
describe command("awk '\$1~/start_servers/{ print \$3}' /etc/php-fpm.d/#{ENV['PJCODE']}.conf") do
  its('stdout.to_i') { should be_within(9.0).of(20.0) }
end
```

上記のコードは以下のように書くのと同じです。

```ruby
describe command("awk '\$1~/start_servers/{ print \$3}' /etc/php-fpm.d/#{ENV['PJCODE']}.conf") do
  it "start_servers は 2から10までの値である" do
    expect(subject.stdout.to_i).to be_within(9.0).of(20.0)
  end
end
```

`its(:stdout) { should 〜 }`と書いた場合、subjectの`stdout`メソッドを呼び出した結果を検証します。

`describe`している対象がcommandリソースタイプなので、subjectには[ServerSpec::Type::Command](https://github.com/mizzy/serverspec/blob/master/lib/serverspec/type/command.rb)が設定されています。

単にシンボルを渡して`its(:stdout)`と書くと`ServerSpec::Type::Command#stdout`が呼び出され、その結果を検証します。

`its`は[rspec/rspec-its](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-its#usage)の機能で、シンボルの他に文字列を受け取ることができ、`.`でつなげるとsubjectの下のネストした属性を取れます。

Comment: さん、回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: Seiei さん、回答ありがとうございます。
ruby 2.2.3p173 および、2.4.0でも試してみたのですが、int へのcastも判定も上手くできました!! 感謝です!!
(ちなみに上記でbe_within の範囲指定の仕方を間違えていたのですが,  http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/2e79a1abe7cd8214caa5#be_within--of を参考にさせていただき、無事に正常な範囲の指定ができるようになりました。)